# Making use of multiple data sources with Zend Framework

Tags: php, oop, zend-framework, zend-db

I am starting an application built on zend framework; this application should be able to make use of multiple data sources other than a database; a webservice for example.

I have been reading on how to structure my model so as to allow for this scenario. I have come across various concepts that seem to provide a solution to this (DataMapper Pattern, Service Pattern, Adapter Layer, etc). However, I am still confused on how to put this all together into a reusable and scalable codebase.

I have worked with zend framework before and will normally work with a mysql table. If for example, I have a Users table...I simple have a Users class in my model that contains business logic of the the user domain and a User class extending Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract representing a row in the user table.

How best do I organize my model and code base such that i can still call $users->fetchAll() and get a collection of user objects regardless of what my datasource is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It basically works the same as you did before, just that instead of a `Zend_Db_Table_Gateway` you use a `My_UserGateway_Whatever`, e.g. create an interface first:

```
interface UserGateway
{
    /**
     * @return array
     * @throws UserGatewayException
     */
    public function findAll();
}
```

We dont want Exceptions from the concrete Gateways to appear in the consuming code, so we add the UserGatewayException as a catch all:

```
 class UserGatewayException extends RuntimeException
 {}
```

Then add a class implementing that interface:

```
class My_UserGateway_Webservice implements UserGateway
{
    public function findAll()
    {
        try {
            // insert logic to fetch from the webservice
            return $userData;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            throw new UserGatewayException($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode, $e);
        }
    }

    // … more code
}
```

Likewise, if you want to use a Database source, you can write an adapter for the Zend_Db_* classes, e.g.

```
class My_UserGateway_Database implements UserGateway
{
    private $tableDataGateway;

    public function __construct(Zend_Db_Table_Abstract $tableDataGateway)
    {
        $this->tableDataGateway = $tableDataGateway;
    }

    public function findAll()
    {
        try {
            return $this->tableDataGateway->select()->blah();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            throw new UserGatewayException($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode, $e);
        }
    }

    // … more code
}
```

If you need another Data Provider, make sure they implement that interface, so you can rely on the `findAll` method to be there. Make your consuming class depend on the interface, e.g.

```
class SomethingUsingUsers
{
    private $userGateway;

    public function __construct(UserGateway $userGateway)
    {
        $this->userGateway = $userGateway;
    }

    public function something()
    {
        try {
            $users = $this->userGateway->findAll();
            // do something with array of user data from gateway
        } catch (UserGatewayException $e) {
            // handle Exception
        }
    }

    // … more code
}
```

Now, when you create `SomethingUsingUsers` you can easily inject one or the other Gateway into the constructor and your code will work regardless of which Gateway you used:

```
$foo = SomethingUsingUsers(
    new My_UserGateway_Database(
        new Zend_Db_Table('User')
    )
)
```

or, for the Webservice:

```
$foo = SomethingUsingUsers(
    new My_UserGateway_Webservice(
        // any additional dependencies
    )
)
```